# How can we disable the checkbox when user check the one of checbox in the Checkboxlist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I've a table in which first row contains a checkbox list. I've a scenario like if user click any checkbox of that list the other should be disabled mode and uncheck the checkbox enable the all checkboxes.

I've tried like to disable the checkbox ,but unable to un-checkbox the checkbox it should to enable all.

```
var $checkboxList = $('#tr1 input[type=checkbox]');
            $checkboxList.change(function () {
                $checkboxList.each(function () {
                    if (!this.checked) {
                        this.disabled = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        this.disabled = false;
                    }
                });
            });
```

how can we hold the state of checkboxes in case of paging ?

Comment: Cant you use radio button instead?

Comment: No I've to use checkbox list as per my requirement.

Answer (score 3):

In answer to your first question, you can just set `.prop('disabled')` based on the value of `this.checked`:

```
$checkboxList.change(function () {
    $checkboxList.not(this).prop('disabled', this.checked); 
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TQk5p/4/)

Comment: How can find the index of the checkbox?Because based on that I've to find the column name fro the thead.

Comment: I want to create a custom method($.fn.checkChange) which can have input parameters as checkboxlist , span Id .How can we do this ? I have tried like this but don't know how to pass the input params.